# UIKit controls visible after pushScene in cocos2d

Tags: uikit, cocos2d-iphone

I've got a scene with two UIKit controls: UITextView. But from this scene, user has possibility to go to another scene to check something and come back. After pushScene the UIKit controls are still visible on screen and user can tap on them and edit them.

How can I get rid of them so that they are not visible after pushScene?
I don't want to remove one scene and add another, as I want to maintain whatever happened in it, this also means I cannot release the controls and create new ones after user does popScene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling pushScene, set the UITextViews as hidden:

```
myTextView.hidden = YES;
```

After popping the pushed scene simply unhide the text fields again. While hidden, UIViews don't receive input events but they remain in the view hierarchy.

Comment: awesome :) thanks for that. Could you please tell me if I can use onEnter to set them back to hidden = NO, or should I use a different method?

Comment: Good question. I believe onEnter is called after popScene but I can't say for sure.

Comment: it is called alright, I was just wondering if there's a better, more 'proper' way to do it. I guess I'll stick with it for now. Thanks again!